# Stop Android TabLayout loading next page automatically

Tags: android, view, tabs, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I've realized when using a tab layout in Android it always loads the tabs touching it, i.e. the tab before and the tab after so it is loaded when you page to it.

However, I load lots of content and images from a server and this causes a lot of data and memory use and I often get `OOM errors`, I am displaying the images efficiently using Glide.

Basically I need to know 3 things:

1. How can I stop the tab layout loading any pages other than the current one
2. How to `clear/recycle/delete` an old tab after you get to a new page to clear up memory
3. How to always refresh the tab when you go back to it

Answer (score 10):

By default it is viewpager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1) , meaning View pager will by default load atleast 1 on the right and one on the left tab of current tab. It is done so, mostly because there is a point when u slide viewpager, when certain area of both tabs is visible. For those smooth transitions preloading is required. You **cannot** set it viewpager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0).
The only way out is to use this method setUserVisibleHint
add this to your fragment

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser) {
        // load data here
    }else{
       // fragment is no longer visible
    }
}
```

This will be called only when that particular tab is visible to user, so only  then u can call all loadfing function. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks , but sometimes setUserVisibleHint is called too quickly , and do things before all